# TFT screen setup troubles

Tags: gpio

I've been trying to my tft screen work with the Pi using a tutorial [here](http://w8bh.net/pi/TFT2.pdf).

The python script doesn't seem to work, I get this error every time I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tft.py", line 49, in <module>
    red = value>>16
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

The script is copy-pasted from the PDF and needed lots of massaging since copying to nano causes all sort of broken lines (comment lines broken up). Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import spidev

BLACK   = 0x000000
RED     = 0xFF0000
GREEN   = 0x00FF00
BLUE    = 0x0000FF
WHITE   = 0xFFFFFF
COLORSET = [RED,GREEN,BLUE,WHITE]

SWRESET = 0x01
SLPOUT  = 0x11
DISPON  = 0x29
CASET   = 0x2A
RASET   = 0x2B
RAMWR   = 0x2C
MADCTL  = 0x36
COLMOD  = 0x3A

def SetPin(pinNumber,value):
    GPIO.output(pinNumber,value)
def InitIO():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(DC,GPIO.OUT)

def WriteByte(value, data=True):
       SetPin(DC,data)
       spi.writebytes([value])
def WriteCmd(value):
       "Send command byte to display"
       WriteByte(value,False)

"sends a 16-bit word to the display as data"
def WriteWord (value):
       WriteByte(value >> 8)
       WriteByte(value & 0xFF)
def WriteList (byteList):
       "Send list of bytes to display, as data"
       for byte in byteList:
              WriteByte(byte)

def Write888(value,width,count):
       "sends a 24-bit RGB pixel data to display, with optional repeat"
red = value>>16                                             #the offending line
green = (value>>8) & 0xFF
blue = value & 0xFF
RGB  = [red,green,blue]
SetPin(DC,1)
for a in range(count):
       spi.writebytes(RGB*width)

def InitDisplay():
       "Resets & prepares display for active use."
WriteCmd  (SWRESET)
time.sleep(0.2)
WriteCmd  (SLPOUT)
time.sleep(0.2)
WriteCmd  (DISPON)


def SetAddrWindow(x0,y0,x1,y1):
       "sets a rectangular display window into which pixel data is placed"
       WriteCmd(CASET)
       WriteWord(x0)
       WriteWord(x1)
       WriteCmd(RASET)
       WriteWord(y0)
       WriteWord(y1)
def FillRect(x0,y0,x1,y1,color):
       "fills rectangle with given color"
       width = x1-x0+1
       height = y1-y0+1
       SetAddrWindow(x0,y0,x1,y1)
       WriteCmd(RAMWR)
       Write888(color,width,height)

def FillScreen(color):
       "Fills entire screen with given color"
       FillRect(0,0,127,159,color)
def ClearScreen():
       "Fills entire screen with black"
       FillRect(0,0,127,159,BLACK)

def TimeDisplay():
       "Measures time required to fill display twice"
       startTime=time.time()
       print "  Now painting screen GREEN"
       FillScreen(GREEN)
       print "  Now clearing screen"
       ClearScreen()
       elapsedTime=time.time()-startTime
       print "  Elapsed time %0.1f seconds" % (elapsedTime)

print "Adafruit 1.8 TFT display demo with hardware SPI"
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.mode = 0
InitIO()
InitDisplay()
TimeDisplay()
spi.close()
print "Done."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer should be simple. You haven't created the variable `value`, that's why the error says `NameError: name 'value' is not defined`. However, that's not true, as `value` is an argument for the function that contains the offending line. Can you comment out that line (`red = value>>16`) and try running it again, and see if you get a similar error again, but from the following line, `green = (value>>8) & 0xFF`? If so, please post the error as an edit on your post.

Comment: Yes, now the it complains about the green line. What shall I do?

Comment: I take it that HeatfanJohn's answer solved it for you. Glad to hear that you got it resolved :D

Comment: Don't know. I've burnt my finger before and I'm never sure when to mark what and how. I'm surely grateful for HeatfanJohn if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: If you're saying you aren't sure if you did the right thing by marking the answer, I think you're just fine. If the answer resolved your issue, marking as answer is just a courtesy, showing you appreciate the time and effort someone put in, as well as making it clear to any readers that this answer is the fix. I personally upvote any answers that are well done and required some effort to put together and/or helped me.

Comment: He solved the original problem but then there are more problems popping up and I still can't use the code and feel lost. Does that mean he solved it? Also, if it's marked 'solved', will I still get help? I got a warning recently, I'm terrified of being banned from stack.

Comment: I highly doubt that you will get banned from SE for not posting correctly. The only reason I know of that you would get banned is for spamming or being a general nuisance and not changing after being talked to by the community and mods. If you are having a new issue that is different than this specific one, but still related, just link to this one, mentioning it as related. The worst that can happen is that the new one gets deleted (then you just edit this question) or merged (with this one).

Comment: As for marking a question as "solved"...Generally, if a question has an answer marked as "solved" it will be left as such, people won't spend too much time putting together more good answers. You may get edits to answers occasionally or even some good answers, but that's relatively rare. You could go to the chat and ping SteveRobillard or Jivings (you can ping by placing the @ symbol prior to the username - they'll get a notification) and ask them if you want more clarification from a mod.

Comment: This is why Python is crap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your formatting in your question was wrong, but the code you show doesn't have correct indentation for the lines starting with `red = value>>16`.  Python uses indentation to denote blocks.  Without the indentation the lines are not a part of `Write888`.

The code below shows the correct indentation.

```
def Write888(value,width,count):
    "sends a 24-bit RGB pixel data to display, with optional repeat"
    red = value>>16                                             #the offending line
    green = (value>>8) & 0xFF
    blue = value & 0xFF
    RGB  = [red,green,blue]
    SetPin(DC,1)
    for a in range(count):
        spi.writebytes(RGB*width)
```

For your second issue `

You need to add this part of the program from the tutorial that is missing from your copy.  Obviously the comments (lines starting with "#" aren't required, but the remaining lines define some constants including `DC`).

```
#TFT to RPi connections 
# PIN TFT RPi 
# 1 backlight 3v3 
# 2 MISO <none> 
# 3 CLK GPIO 24 
# 4 MOSI GPIO 23 
# 5 CS-TFT GND 
# 6 CS-CARD <none> 
# 7 D/C GPIO 25 
# 8 RESET <none> 
# 9 VCC 3V3 
# 10 GND GND 

SCLK = 24 
SDAT = 23 
DC = 25 
pins = [SCLK,SDAT,DC]
```

Comment: I don't think so. I still get an error then:   File "tft.py", line 48
    red = value>>16                                             #the offending line
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Can you post your updated program listing?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that? You mean post the same code? Where can I post the script?

Comment: Post the code exactly as you have it formatted now. We need to check that you don't have any extra spaces in any lines

Comment: Thank you for you kind help! Wasn't sure where to post it, does this help? http://codepad.org/cUJtt6ff

Comment: As I expected, you need one more space on the line `""sends a ...`, the "r" in "red" needs to be exactly under the double quote.  You also need more spaces on line 54, the `rpi.writebytes` needs to be indented more than the `for` line above it.  Python is very picky on how lines are indented.  Your code needs to be indented as I have shown in the answer.

Comment: Ok, after the changes it complains about the next block (line 58) which means the formatting is OK. I think I can format the code using your advice. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I updated your codepad code here: http://codepad.org/ATmXgMr4  I've never used codepad before, I didn't `save` it, will the link stay active without saving it?

Comment: It seems to have two lines added (108 instead of 106) so I guess it works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I still get errors: Adafruit 1.8 TFT display demo with hardware SPI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tft.py", line 104, in <module>
    InitIO()
  File "tft.py", line 28, in InitIO
    GPIO.setup(DC,GPIO.OUT)
NameError: global name 'DC' is not defined

Comment: See my updated answer.  You have lines of Python code missing from your program that are included in the source code shown in part 1 of the tutorial you are following: http://w8bh.net/pi/TFT1.pdf

Comment: Cool looking inexpensive display ... I think I'll get one myself! ;-)